# Is there a button on the keyboard that does nothing?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to bind a button on my mouse to one on my keyboard, but the one on my keyboard needs to do nothing except serve as my Ventrilo hotkey.  For some weird reason I can't bind things like <kbd>Shift</kbd> (unless its a <kbd>Shift</kbd> + key kind of thing).

Does anyone know of a key on an average keyboard that does nothing?

Comment: On a related note: http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/home-row-computing

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<kbd>CAPS LOCK</kbd>

Comment: BUT EVERYONE LOVES CAPS LOCK!

Comment: You spelt Billy Mays wrong.

Comment: R        I        P

Comment: I disagree that capslock does 'nothing'.  It's a way to prevent you from being able to log in after your screensaver activates, forcing you to call into the IT help desk to reset your password since you exceeded the bad login attempts.

Answer (score 11):

<kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd>. It's what I use for my Vent key. I've never missed it when doing stuff while chatting in Vent.

Comment: Its not like Scroll Lock has no use at all... one can use it on Excel to scroll through the document without moving the cell cursor (or whatever it's called). I do agree though that most apps don't seem to have a use for Scroll Lock.

Comment: Scroll Lock and Num Lock have an issue where the PTT binding will break if you press ctrl before or mid-way through due to a backwards functionality feature.  Pause/break is similar but less frequent in that it can be activated accidentaly via ctrl+Num/Scrol Lock.
---
From wikipedia:
> Pressing Ctrl+Scroll Lock performs the same function as pressing Ctrl+Pause/Break. This behavior is a remnant of the original IBM PC keyboards, which did not have a dedicated Pause/Break key. Instead, they assigned the Pause function to Ctrl+Num Lock and the Break function to Ctrl+Scroll Lock.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on your keyboard. Usually the medium to high F-keys (<kbd>F13</kbd>–<kbd>F16</kbd> on my older Apple keyboard) aren't used for much. On Windows keyboards, scroll lock isn't used much. Is there not a way to set Ventrilo to use a mouse button rather than a key?

Comment: Awwww man! You beat me by 13 seconds. :)

Comment: "Is there not a way to set Ventrilo to use a mouse button?"  Windows can bind mouse buttons 1-5.  If I want to bind button 6 or 7 I need to map them to a key on my keyboard.

Comment: It's a Windows limitation? That's interesting...
@Dan: sorry! Though considering that my response is 2 or 3 times longer `:P`

Comment: @jtbandes: I always thought it was a windows limitation... but I could be wrong.

Comment: there are more than 12 function keys?

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd>
- <kbd>Pause</kbd> (though <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>pause</kbd> does do something)
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd>

Though all these keys tend to be piled together in a hard-to-reach area in the keyboard.

Comment: Pause is super helpful when playing flash games!

Comment: Pause does stuff; just open most any decent game and pressing it will pause it.

Answer (score 1):

I used <kbd>~</kbd> (which is next to the <kbd>1</kbd> on my QWERTY board) and it worked fine for Ventrillo while playing World of Warcraft.

However the only annoyance is typing while having to click that button :P You will erase selected text or just have to live with clicking that isn't editable.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>F7</kbd> - <kbd>F10</kbd> rarely do anything. Or you can try <kbd>Win</kbd>+[key].

Opera, for some inexplicable reason, uses <kbd>F8</kbd> by default for selecting the address bar (every other browser and file manager uses <kbd>F6</kbd>). One app (KATE I think) uses <kbd>F10</kbd> for word wrap, so I added this to other apps where possible.

Comment: F7 - caret browsing in many browsers. F10 goes to the menu bar. And you don't seem to have used any Orthodox File Manager, apparently :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have a keyboard with several "extra" keys I don't actually use or want, so I'd remap my "Email" or "power off" key to the other purpose.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> is always the first to go on my set ups, usually remapped to standard <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

Comment: Do that on a German keyboard and you can't type "@" any more :/
(not to mention {,[,],} or \ ). Yes, coding is tough here :)